# Can matplotlib pick_event return array indeces rather than values or pixels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to write a point picker for a plot in matplotlib. I'd like it to tell me the i, j indeces of the plotted array where I have clicked. It seems that the only options are for event.mouseevent.xdata, which is in terms of the plotted coordinate values, or event.mouseevent.x, which is in terms of pixels (from what I can see "pixels" isn't the same as grid boxes i.e. what I'm looking for).

Have I misunderstood what xdata/x are. Is there a way to do what I want.

Thanks
Niall

EDIT: the image being clicked on is a 2D array plot, for instance with pcolormesh

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979953/use-matplotlib-pick-event-to-trigger-when-center-of-pcolormesh-squares-are-click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can:

- first make your artist (the array in the example below) pickable.
- on click action, check that the click is on the artist
- use the `event.ind[0]` property to get the index.

Further documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html). Example follows:

```
from numpy import linspace
from numpy import cos
from numpy import pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = linspace(0,1,100)
y = cos(x*8*pi)   # your array

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b',picker=10)

def onpick(event):

    if event.artist!=line:  #check that you clicked on the object you wanted
        return True     
    if not len(event.ind):  #check the index is valid
        return True
    ind = event.ind[0]

    ax.plot(x[ind],y[ind],'ro')

    fig.canvas.draw() 
    return True

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
fig.show()
```

[image]

EDIT: Ok. Then you can first plot a line exactly at your grid points, then draw your pcolormesh object above, and hide the line. Here's the code

```
x = linspace(0,9,10)+.5
y = linspace(0,9,10)+.5   # your array
x,y=meshgrid(x,y)
x=x.flatten()
y=y.flatten()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

line, = ax.plot(x, y, 'b',picker=10)
line.set_visible(False)
ax.pcolormesh(np.random.randn(10,10))

def onpick(event):

    if event.artist!=line:  #check that you clicked on the object you wanted
        return True     
    if not len(event.ind):  #check the index is valid
        return True
    ind = event.ind[0]

    ax.plot(x[ind],y[ind],'ro')

    fig.canvas.draw() 
    return True

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry - my fault for not framing the question clearly enough. I want to pick on a 2D array. The event.ind is helpful, but I'm not sure what the results are: it returns between one and four numbers. I'd like to convert them to i and j. Question edited above.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I've green ticked you because it does what I need, however, it seems a bit unsatisfactory to me. Basically it involves making a invisible new plot to act as a proxy - which seems a bit awkward to me

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue and got it to work. First off though, it's helpful if you post some sample code. Here is something I re-jigged from a different example I had used for updating embedded charts, but I had to add a picker anyway. The issue I've run into now is that for a pcolormesh the picker only returns when you click on the border (gg349 technically solves that... but difficult to implement IMO). If you run the below code and click the plot button and click on the borders of cells though you can see how I return the "data" points (in this case just the label indices, but you get the jist:

```
In [1]
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#import matplotlib.animation as animation
#from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

def customplot(f,X):
    try:
        f.clf()
    except:
        None
    try:
        ax=ax
    except:
        ax=f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.pcolormesh(X,picker=True)
    ax.set_yticks(arange(0.5,len(X)+0.5))
    ax.set_xticks(arange(0.5,len(X)+0.5))
    ax.set_yticklabels(["LabY"+str(l) for l in range(len(X))])
    ax.set_xticklabels(["LabX"+str(l) for l in range(len(X))])

class My_GUI:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.canvas1=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f,self.master)
        self.updatechartbutton=tk.Button(master=master,text='update plot',command=self.drawcustomplot)
        self.canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='x',expand=True)
        self.canvas1.mpl_connect('pick_event',self.onpick)
        self.toolbar=NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas1,master)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.toolbar.pack(side='top',fill='x')           
        self.updatechartbutton.pack(side='top')

    def drawcustomplot(self):
        self.X=array(np.random.normal(size=[3,3]))
        customplot(self.f,self.X)
        #plt.xticks([1,2,3],['one','two','three'])
        self.canvas1.show()

    def onpick(self,event):
        print('Returned indices')
        print(event.ind)
        print('mapping back:')
        self.myxlabels=["LabX"+str(l) for l in range(len(self.X))]
        self.myylabels=["LabY"+str(l) for l in range(len(self.X))]
        self.ypos=event.ind[0] / 3
        self.xpos=event.ind[0] % 3
        print("Y: "+str(self.myylabels[self.ypos])+'  X:'+str(self.myxlabels[self.xpos]))


root=tk.Tk()
gui=My_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

and as you click you can see it returns the index, and then my re-mapped points:

```
Out [1]
Returned indices
[2]
mapping back:
Y: LabY0  X:LabX2
Returned indices
[1]
mapping back:
Y: LabY0  X:LabX1
Returned indices
[7]
mapping back:
Y: LabY2  X:LabX1
Returned indices
[8]
mapping back:
Y: LabY2  X:LabX2
Returned indices
[5 8]
mapping back:
Y: LabY1  X:LabX2
```

For example in my last click, i clicked on the border between middle-right and top-right, returning index [5 8] (the 5th box and 8th box counting from the bottom-left to top-right along rows first. Here I always say take the first index (so if you click on the top of the box you want it would return the correct index). so here we correctly return Row Y1 and column X2.

I know this may not be ideal, and I'm still playing around with ways to get it to be the center of the boxes that trigger the event, but at least shows you how to get some data back from the indices returned from pcolormesh pickers.

---

In case my example wasn't clear, here is a visualization of my 'last' click. The numbers are the index returned from event.ind from each box, the red circle around 5 indicates that's the index my code finds labels for and returns when I click around where the yellow circle is.
[image]

Comment: @nrob See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43979953/use-matplotlib-pick-event-to-trigger-when-center-of-pcolormesh-squares-are-click for more information on fixing the issue of requiring a click on the edge vs anywhere in the box you want.