# Use matplotlib pick event to trigger when center of pcolormesh squares are clicked?

Tags: python, matplotlib, picker, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a broader project, but am running into an issue using matplotlibs `picker=True` and `pick_event` with a pcolormesh. It works, but is not intuitive as the pick event is only triggered when i click along the edges of the heatmap 'boxes', and it returns the surrounding indices (so if you click a corner 4 indices are returned by the intersection of the 4 boxes at that point).

For example, in the following picture when I click near the yellow circle my picker returns indices [5 8] (5 is the box below and 8 above). Instead, I'd like to return only index 5 when that 'box' is clicked.
[image: pcolormesh picker]

Here is the code I used to exemplify my issue:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
#import matplotlib.animation as animation
#from matplotlib import style
import numpy as np

import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

def customplot(f,X):
    try:
        f.clf()
    except:
        None
    try:
        ax=ax
    except:
        ax=f.add_subplot(111)
    ax.pcolormesh(X,picker=True)
    ax.set_yticks(arange(0.5,len(X)+0.5))
    ax.set_xticks(arange(0.5,len(X)+0.5))
    ax.set_yticklabels(["LabY"+str(l) for l in range(len(X))])
    ax.set_xticklabels(["LabX"+str(l) for l in range(len(X))])

class My_GUI:

    def __init__(self,master):
        self.master=master
        self.f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)
        self.canvas1=FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.f,self.master)
        self.canvas1.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='x',expand=True)
        self.canvas1.mpl_connect('pick_event',self.onpick)
        self.toolbar=NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(self.canvas1,master)
        self.toolbar.update()
        self.toolbar.pack(side='top',fill='x')           
        self.drawcustomplot()

    def drawcustomplot(self):
        self.X=array(np.random.normal(size=[3,3]))
        customplot(self.f,self.X)
        #plt.xticks([1,2,3],['one','two','three'])
        self.canvas1.show()

    def onpick(self,event):
        print('Returned indices')
        print(event.ind)
        print('mapping back:')
        self.myxlabels=["LabX"+str(l) for l in range(len(self.X))]
        self.myylabels=["LabY"+str(l) for l in range(len(self.X))]
        self.ypos=event.ind[0] / 3
        self.xpos=event.ind[0] % 3
        print("Y: "+str(self.myylabels[self.ypos])+'  X:'+str(self.myxlabels[self.xpos]))


root=tk.Tk()
gui=My_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

*this is further to the question found here: [Can matplotlib pick_event return array indeces rather than values or pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21851114/can-matplotlib-pick-event-return-array-indeces-rather-than-values-or-pixels/43946717#43946717). I'd like to avoid trying to draw an underlying scatterplot that is masked by the pcolormesh, but handles the picker events if possible as I feel there must be a simpler way to achieve the desired result.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to use a `button_press_event` here. From that you can easily obtain the coordinates of the clicked pixel. In the case of an `imshow` plot it's even easier,

```
x = int(np.round(event.xdata))
y = int(np.round(event.ydata))
```

Complete example (using `imshow`):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X=np.array(np.random.normal(size=[3,3]))

myxlabels=["LabX"+str(l) for l in range(len(X[0,:]))]
myylabels=["LabY"+str(l) for l in range(len(X))]
plt.imshow(X)
plt.xticks(range(len(X[0,:])),myxlabels )
plt.yticks(range(len(X)),myylabels )

def onclick(event):
    print('Returned indices')
    print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
    print('mapping back:')
    x = int(np.round(event.xdata))
    y = int(np.round(event.ydata))
    tx = "Y: {}, X: {}, Value: {:.2f}".format(myylabels[y], myxlabels[x], X[y,x])
    print(tx)

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Aha, thank you, `button_press_event` was perfect! I really still prefer to use pcolormesh as I make use of `.set_bad()` and other pcolormesh-specific (as far as I understand) functionality. I know similar things are still possible with imshow, but no sense changing IMO as I just tested and your fix works with pcolormesh as I get the coordinates returned and can easily transform that back into what I need.

Comment: Yes, so the difference is just that in pcolormesh the coordinates are shifted by 0.5, which you will need to take into accound.

Comment: Ah yes, also imshow coord system starts with (0,0) at the top-left of the plot vs. bottom-left, but not hard to modify to work in either case.

Comment: `imshow` starts at `-0.5`, as `0` is the center of the first pixel. That is sure easy to adapt to.